# How to make a "join" between two tables?

Tags: table, inner, reference

I have a table `Product2`, witch contain products.
I have a table `PricebookEntry`, witch contain price for products.

How can i make a request for someting like :

```
SELECT Id, desriprtion, title, [...]
FROM Product2
INNER JOIN PricebookEntry ON PricebookEntry.Product2Id=Product2.Id
WHERE Product2.reference LIKE '%MyProductRef%'
```

I need to select the products info and their price but they are not in the same table.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Take a look at this topic:  
[A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) and scroll down to the `SOQL Joins`

Comment: Okay, i solved the problem by ckecking "Child Relationships" on the Force.com IDE.
I have all the fields i need, but how can i display them on my visualforce page ?
I make a apex:repeat, but how can i call the filed of the child records ?

Comment: You need to access the child relationship name like a list: `<apex:repeat value="{!Product2.ChildRelationshipName__r}" var="child">{!child.UnitPrice}`

Comment: @mast0r Yes it works ! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
SELECT Id, description, title, [...] 
FROM Product2 
WHERE Id in (SELECT Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry) AND reference LIKE '%MyProductRef%');
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but i can't select fields from PricebookEntry.
For exemple, i need to select the field PricebookEntry.UnitPrice

Comment: @CotralLab You can select these fields through the relation ship access, something like: `SELECT Id, description, title, (Select UnitPrice From PricebookEntryRelationShipName__r) From Product2 ...`

Comment: There are no 'joins' (syntax-wise) in SOQL, so the link above from mast0r is your best friend to get the return you need using the Relationship syntax.